# WSO2 api manager with IS for SSO

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to integration wso2 am (store and publisher component)with an external IdP to enable SSO.
So, I'm using WSO2 IS as a bridge for that.
The documentation says that we should share WSO2 AM and IS users store (I know that the store or publisher require some specific roles for access),but this doesn't make sense to share users data store and if that why is than the benefit of using an external IS that centralize and handle authentication.
Can we pass the store and publisher required roles throught the SAML response?

Comment: was it possible to send required roles through the SAML response?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, you need to share the user store between API Manager and IS in order to provision the users in APIM side. As mentioned in [1] you need this for the purpose of authenticating the user based on login credentials entered in redirected IS page and authenticating him based on the roles and permissions of the system.

If you are unable to share the user store with your external IDP or WSO2 IS, then you would need to do JIT provisioning in APIM side by writing a custom extension. You should send the roles through SAML response. This extension should read the SAML response and create/update users in APIM user store using the roles sent in the SAML response. You could either add the role mappings in IS or you could map roles coming in the SAML response to existing APIM roles via the custom extension itself by keeping those role mappings in a sperate property file. Hope this answers your question !

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM2xx/Configuring+External+IDP+through+Identity+Server+for+SSO